# Angular 4 unexpected end of json in service get

Tags: angular

I' m getting unexpected end of JSON error when i use this code in the service to get a client:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ClientsService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    getClient(clientId: number): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(`/api/client/getbyid/` + clientId)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }
}
```

when i modify this code, that error dissappears.

```
 getClient(clientId: number) {
        return this.http.get(`/api/client/getbyid/` + clientId)
        .map((res: Response) => res);
 }
```

I don't understand why the error happens in the first case but not in the second. Why does it behaves like that ?

Comment: Because in the first case, you try to parse the body as JSON, whereas you don't in the second case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `HttpClient` (which was introduced in `angular 4.3`), then now by default response is serialized to `json`. Since `HttpClient` depends on `Content-Type` in reponse `headers`.